# How can I get chinese character using raw_input

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

my dev enviroment is: eclipse+pydev.

If I use raw_input() to get character, I input "你好世界", then I get "浣犲ソ涓栫晫". Then how can I get "你好世界" and print it correctly.

I have tried raw_input().decode(sys.stdin.encoding), but the result is same.

Comment: How exactly do you get `浣犲ソ涓栫晫`? I.E, where did you find this result

Comment: In [1]: s = raw_input()
你好世界

In [2]: print s.decode('utf-8')
你好世界

In [3]: print s.decode('gbk')
浣犲ソ涓栫晫

Comment: What is the code you're using for this so far? This is in the python terminal, I guess?

Comment: I just copy the characters from my IDE console panel.

Comment: Switched from -1 to +1 for you are clearly showing effort in this... but you are still not showing us the details, something is missing from the question...

Comment: If you do: import sys; print sys.stdin.encoding in pydev, which encoding do you get?

Answer (score 3):

Decode using the terminal's/console's code page.

```
import sys

t = raw_input().decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
print t
```

Comment: @user2705767: if this doesn't work, then it's probably either your terminal emulator setting or your keyboard language setting that is borken. What does the terminal echo when typing?

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding you are using. Based on [@imom0's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371083/how-can-i-get-chinese-character-using-raw-input#comment26975275_18371083), I went and tried `gbk` encoding. Specifically, this is my python 2.7.3 interpreter with UTF-8 encoding via `ibus` for input:

```
>>> print raw_input().decode('gbk')
你好世界
浣犲ソ涓栫晫
>>> print raw_input().decode('utf-8')
你好世界
你好世界
```

This is the result of trying to decode a UTF-8 encoded string as `gbk`. Since your input seems to be some form of UTF, why not enforce either utf-8 decoding or use the input's encoding to decode it, as in [@ignacio-vazquez-abrams' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18371117/1091386)?

```
import sys

print myString.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please edit the question to update what doesn't work and what you see..